# Try to run (ng serve) but it keeps asking to update @angular/cli but (ng update @angular/cli) doesn't work

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I try to run my angular project using `ng serve`, but this error is showing:

```
The Angular CLI configuration format has been changed, and your existing
configuration can be updated automatically by running the following command:

    ng update @angular/cli
```

And I run the same command, then when I try to run `ng serve`, and it shows this error again, and again.

**Here is the output in my terminal:**

```
$ ng serve

The Angular CLI configuration format has been changed, and your existing
configuration can be updated automatically by running the following command: 

    ng update @angular/cli

$ ng update @angular/cli

$ ng serve  

The Angular CLI configuration format has been changed, and your existing
configuration can be updated automatically by running the following command:

    ng update @angular/cli
```

**Also, this is Angular configuration:**

```
Angular CLI: 6.2.3
Node: 10.9.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 6.1.9
@angular-devkit/architect         0.8.3
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.8.3
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.8.3
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.8.3
@angular-devkit/core              0.8.3
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.8.3
@angular/cli                      6.2.3
@ngtools/webpack                  6.2.3
@schematics/angular               0.8.3
```

Comment: `npm install @angular/cli`

Comment: It doesn't work either :(

Comment: Try `npm update -g @angular/cli`

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Comment: What npm version are you on?

Comment: Also try npm install -g @angular/cli

Comment: npm : 6.4.1
npm install -g @angular/cli this is actually doesn't solve the problem :(

Comment: What is the value of @angular/cli in your package.json look like?

Comment: "@angular/cli": "^6.2.3"

Comment: Try just `ng update`

Comment: No. doesn't work :((((((

Comment: what about npm update -g @angular/cli and then try to just generate a new project....if it works, then just copy your existing project files over to the new project.